# How to edit code refactor (all in one line) code style?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I have such code

```
override fun onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus: Boolean)
    {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus)
        if (hasFocus)
        {
            // Standard Android full-screen functionality.
            // Use for hide status bar and navigation buttons
            window.decorView.systemUiVisibility =
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE or
                            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION or
                            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN or
                            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION or
                            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN or
                            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY

            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON)
        }
    }
```

Now it looks like it should be, but if I try to code refactor `ctrl + alt + L` I get this

```
override fun onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus: Boolean)
    {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus)
        if (hasFocus)
        {
            // Standard Android full-screen functionality.
            // Use for hide status bar and navigation buttons
            window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY

            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON)
        }
    }
```

Like everything go to one line.

I checked `File -> Settings` , `Editor -> Code style -> Kotlin`, but I did not find there to fix it...

Question is, how to fix it?

Comment: True, i found nothing about them as well, you could file an issue for feature request at jetbrains (youtrack) or contact official kotlin slack (https://kotlinlang.slack.com), could email you to directly to join the slack without 24 hour registration if you provide below